# Javascript override for “Place Order button” using custom Woocommerce payment gateway

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway

I am currently developing a custom Woocommerce payment gateway that receives credit card details via an inline popup. The gateway expects the user to click a button, then the popup loads and the user can enter his card details.

It all works fine, but the user experience flow isn't as expected because the user has to click two buttons one after the other, to checkout.

What I have done: After choosing the gateway, the user clicks a button which loads the inline popup, enters payment details and if authorized, the javascript callback sends a transaction reference as a hidden field, which is submitted when the user clicks "place order". This works well but it is not intuitive or UX-friendly to click two buttons. An unsuspecting user might click the "Place Order" button first, which triggers errors since the payment process isn't yet done.

What I want to achieve: User simply clicks "Place order", and BEFORE the order is processed, it runs the gateway JavaScript function, loads the secure inline popup as usual, and after authorization I can call-back the normal flow of the Place order button.

What I have considered: Making custom copies of the checkout form and scripts and placing in the theme. But the payment gateway script is a plugin and should be independent of the theme.

P.S. I posted this on WordPress Stack xchange earlier but I can't get any attention there.

Comment: You could add something like `$("form.woocommerce-checkout").on('submit', function(){ return gateway(...)} )`.

Comment: Is the sandbox you've posted with or without your code? It appears to be without it, but a sample with your code might be a bit more useful

Comment: @Kenney:  The problem with that is that I need to pass the result from the gateway (in javascript) back to the "normal flow" of the woocommerce order process (php). I feel there might be some woocommerce hook or something that I don't know about.

Comment: @Rob: It is a whole lot of code in multiple files (that's how a wp plugin usually is) so I don't know what is relevant to post. I was thinking maybe from testing out the sandbox maybe you could see my problem, and I could get some pointers that I could follow up in the documentation?

Comment: That's what that line of code does: you inject a JS into the page that adds a Javascript hook to the submitting of the place order form, that *"runs the gateway javascript function,"*, and updates the form with the result. It then returns true to have the form submitted, false if not. The *normal* flow is: you place the order, are redirected to the PSP, pay or cancel, get redirected back to shop page.

Comment: Oh sorry if I am having a dumb moment, but javascript isn't my thing. It's php I'm more familiar with. Do you mean the form will submit anyway after the javascript has executed? Will the form wait for the javascript process to return true? If the javascript returns false does that mean the form won't submit? Thanks!

Comment: Exactly. It will wait, and only submit if the function returns true. You could have a look at the standard paypal plugin to see how they do it, it's integrated with the woocommerce workflow.

Comment: I'm so much closer to a solution now, thank you. However the form is still submitting without waiting for the javascript (though the js loads after the first submission anyway). I will check out paypal now. If you could please post as an answer, then I can accept it.

jQuery("form.woocommerce-checkout").on('submit', function(){
  var result = gatewayFunction();
  return result;
});

Comment: Thanks for the offer, but if it doesn't work, then don't accept it as an answer, ok? I know too little about your code to be sure. I did put it in an answer for readability and updated it a bit. You should check the browser console (F12) for any errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the entire JavaScript you need to inject into the page:

```
jQuery( function($) {     
  $("form.woocommerce-checkout")
  .on('submit', function() { return gatewayFunction( this ); } ); 
} );
```

The outer `jQuery( function($) {` and `} );` make sure that the code in between only gets run when the HTML document is loaded (that way the the `<form>` will exist by the time that code will run), and makes `jQuery` available as `$` in between.

The `return gatewayFunction( this )` passes the `<form>` to the function, so it can use it's values and add or update a hidden payment token field, so you'll need to add that parameter to the `gatewayFunction`:

```
function gatewayFunction( form ) {
  ...
  return is_payment_complete;
}
```

Comment: It works fine now (rather than pass the form back, what I did was to update a hidden field when the payment is done, then check for the value before submitting the form). You're amazing. Thank you!
Funny how it turns out that my problem had to do with understanding javascript form submissions, and nothing to do with woocommerce!

Comment: @Kenney i have written this javascript code of on submit and when i submit checkout form onclick checkout form and in js code i have written `return false` but still form is submitted and order is placing..so can you please provide me any solution or what m i doing wrong.

Comment: it is not working well for me, is there an updated code?